# Create some features based on the mean of y for the month over the past few years

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assuming we have dataset `df` (which can be downloaded from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dryp5g496x6uhe8xmbm7w/sample_data_2022-10-16.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=4n6spcsts8qlbw4noncv5zp03)), I want to create some features based on the mean of y for the month of the past several years, for example: `y_avg_last2`, `y_avg_last3`, `y_avg_last4`, etc., for September 2022, `y_avg_last2` = The mean of September 2021 and September 2020, y_avg_last3 = the mean of September 2021, September 2020, September 2019.

The code I use is as follows, which is relatively repetitive and trivial:

```
df['y_shift12'] = df['y'].shift(12)
df['y_shift24'] = df['y'].shift(24)
df['y_shift36'] = df['y'].shift(36)
df['y_avg_last2'] = df.loc[:, 'y_shift12': 'y_shift24'].mean(axis=1)
df['y_avg_last3'] = df.loc[:, 'y_shift12': 'y_shift36'].mean(axis=1)
df.drop(['y_shift12', 'y_shift24', 'y_shift36'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

How can the desired result be achieved more concisely?

```
df.tail(10)
```

Out:

[image]

```
df.head(10)
```

Out:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Pandas, how to calculate mean values of the past n years for every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837481/pandas-how-to-calculate-mean-values-of-the-past-n-years-for-every-month)

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the shifted columns in a separate object so you don't have to drop from the dataframe after. Combine that with loops for conciseness:

```py
shifted = np.array([df["y"].shift(i) for i in [12, 24, 36]]).T
for i in range(2, 4):
    df[f"y_avg_last{i}"] = shifted[:, :i].mean(axis=1)
```